# Ubunut 14.04.3 LTS network stopped working on VMWare

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-player

After restart, networking suddenly stopped working and I'm unable to connect to internet.
**ifconfig -a**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:c9:1a:f3  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fec9:1af3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6630 (6.6 KB)  TX bytes:11913 (11.9 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:43332 (43.3 KB)  TX bytes:43332 (43.3 KB)
```

I'm getting some weird errors:`Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000` but I'm not sure what these mean.

**cat /procinterrupts**

```
           CPU0       
   0:         25   IO-APIC-edge      timer
   1:         90   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
   3:          1   IO-APIC-edge    
   4:         79   IO-APIC-edge    
   6:          2   IO-APIC-edge      floppy
   8:          1   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
   9:          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
  12:       2692   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  14:          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
  15:          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
  16:       2034   IO-APIC   16-fasteoi   vmwgfx, snd_ens1371
  17:      11702   IO-APIC   17-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, ioc0
  18:         62   IO-APIC   18-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb2
  19:        156   IO-APIC   19-fasteoi   eth0
  24:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  25:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  26:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  27:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  28:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  29:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  30:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  31:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  32:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  33:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  34:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  35:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  36:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  37:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  38:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  39:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  40:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  41:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  42:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  43:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  44:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  45:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  46:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  47:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  48:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  49:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  50:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  51:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  52:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  53:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  54:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  55:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
  56:        160   PCI-MSI-edge      0000:02:05.0
  57:         76   PCI-MSI-edge      vmw_vmci
  58:          0   PCI-MSI-edge      vmw_vmci
 NMI:          0   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:      23109   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
 IWI:          0   IRQ work interrupts
 RTR:          0   APIC ICR read retries
 RES:          0   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:          0   Function call interrupts
 TLB:          0   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:          1   Machine check polls
 HYP:          0   Hypervisor callback interrupts
 ERR:          0
 MIS:          0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing `bridge` in `VMWare Network Manager`

[image]